# Check the existence of a session (Nginx)

Tags: php, session, nginx

I have two sessions in PHP:

```
$_SESSION["session"]["key"] = md5 ($token . $userAgent . $ip);
$_SESSION["session"]["timeout"] = time ();
```

Just want to check that sessions with nginx, tried this code without success:

```
location / {
    if ($request_filename ~* "index.php") {
        break;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~* "session") {
        break;
    }

    rewrite ^.+$ https://localhost/index.php last;
}
```

Any clues ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a cookie just holds the Session ID, an id is always created upon `session_start();` so if your calling that within your script the user will always have a session id.

your best bet is too add a second cookie:

```
setcookie('session_key',md5 ($token . $userAgent . $ip));
```

then within nginx:

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "session_key")
{
    break;
}
```

to check if that cookie is set.

If the hash is sensitive then do this:

```
setcookie('session_key_active','1');
```

Then in Nginx:

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "session_key_active")
{
    break;
}
```

But this is still vulnerable , always check server side values match!

Comment: Thank you for helping me but I cant put the 'key' into a cookie, anyone can get that, security reasons.