# Redirect NGINX based on session variable

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to determine if a user has logged in with NGINX, if they have, redirect them to a web page, if not, redirect them to a login portal. To do this I am currently calling a PHP page which checks for a the session variable, if it exist, I call the same sub domain that got them there, this time with a argument that NGINX can check, I check the variable and redirect them to the correct page. This currently isn't working.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /site/here/;

    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name sub.domain.name www.sub.domain.name;

    location / {
            if ($arg_variable) {
                    proxy_pass https://domain.name:port;
            }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param subdomain "docs";
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

Comment: this can be done using a cookie. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542149/check-the-existence-of-a-session-nginx) is a good example.

Comment: Thanks! That works!